# SD elasticsearch findby with null parameter does not return null

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

with spring-data-jpa, in a JpaRepository with a method 

`Data findByUuid(final String uuid);`

i can call this method with 'null' as the uuid parameter and it results in a null return value.

but with spring-data-elasticsearch, in a ElasticsearchRepository with the same method

```
ElasticsearchData findByUuid(final String uuid);
```

i call this method with 'null' as the uuid parameter, but i don't get back a null value, but a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 1 but found X results
```

where X is the total count of all currently stored documents

how can i implement a findByX(String y) method where a null parameter results in a null return value ?